# Bootstrap container-fluid with flex body Chrome and Firefox

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, css, flexbox

Getting strange behaviour in both Chrome and Firefox with a flex body that contains a container-fluid div.

```css
html, body {
    height: 100%;
    min-height: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
}

body {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
}

.body-content {
    display: flex;
    flex-flow: column;
    flex: 1 1 auto;
  background: yellow;
}

.footer {    
    background: #930D25;
    color: #fff;
    text-align: center;
    height: 45px;
    font-family: segoe ui,Arial,sans-serif;
    flex: 0 0 auto;
    z-index:3;
}
```

```html
<header class="navbar navbar-inverse">Header stuff</header>
<div class="container-fluid body-content">
  <h2>Stuff</h2>
  <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-8">
            Garbage
      </div>
  </div>
</div>
<footer class="footer">
    <div>
        <p>our cool site</p>
    </div>
</footer>
```

Looks fine in IE but the container-fluid div is being squashed to just enough space for its content in both Chrome and Firefox.
Note, it doesn't happen in the code snippet - need to look at it here https://www.bootply.com/BDTqdq0jBk to see the problem.

Comment: https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/f/flex/

Comment: Might be missing something, but that link on the basics of flex hasn't told me anything to solve this problem.

Answer (score 0):

I remove the body {display: flex} to solve the issue, I got the same issue whereby the scrollbar on Chrome did not appear